# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up') in styled Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am Getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up')` while running the below code:
I could not compile my react js

**At Index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import './index.css';

import App from './App';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';

import { theme } from './Components/Theme';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(

  <React.StrictMode>

    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>

  </React.StrictMode>

);

reportWebVitals();
```

***At Theme.js***
Now at the theme.js using material ui Anyone help me.

import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

export const theme = createTheme({

```
palette: {
    primary: {
        main: "#000",
        light: "#543"
    },
    secondary: {
        main:"#arbs3",
    },
    otherCo: {
        main:"#999"
    }
}
```

})

***Then At NavBar.jsx***

```js
const SearchIcon = styled(Box)(({theme})=>({

    display: 'none',
    padding: '1rem',
    gap: '12px',
    alignItems: 'center',
    //small or greater so We used up
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        display: 'flex',
    }
}))
```

Comment: Can you post code for Theme component

Comment: What mui version is it?

Comment: its 5.8.1 @IgorGonak

Comment: I don't see the code of your component

Comment: Okay now i guess you can see @Nemanja

Comment: This looks good to me. Make sure that you are using right import for styled in SearchIcon component

Comment: Okay then I will see But I guess this is right Can you help me

Comment: I mean styled() function, how do you import it? You use it here : const SearchIcon = styled(Box)(({theme})

Comment: import styled from 'styled-components'

Comment: Shoud be import styled from "@mui/material/styles"

Comment: Great, I will post that as answer. Please accept it

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good to me.

Only thing that you need to check is that you are using right import for `styled()` function.

You should import it like this:

```
import {styled} from "@mui/material/styles"
```